# Inserting data with one to one relationship - realm

Tags: swift, realm

So i'm trying to set up and pre populate a database for later use when the actual application ships.

The issue i'm having is i'm not able to insert into the field which is creating the relationship the field is just empty. Screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot should type field is empty]
These are my data models

**The data model holding the info the type is the key to the other object**

```
class sourceRecentData: Object {

    // Name
    dynamic var sourceName: String = ""

    // Description
    dynamic var sourceDesc: String = ""

    // TypeID
    dynamic var type : sourceType?

    // Key
    dynamic var sourceKey: String = ""

    // Enabled
    dynamic var sourceEnabled: Bool = true

    // Unlocked
    dynamic var sourceUnlocked: Bool = false
}
```

**The id in this object links to the object above**

```
class sourceType: Object {

    // NewsType
    dynamic var typeOfNews: String = ""


}
```

**The method i'm using to perform the insert for now it's just dummy data**

```
func createTopDB() {

    let recentData = sourceRecentData()


    let realm = try! Realm()

    recentData.sourceName = "dfdfd"
    recentData.sourceDesc = "fdfd"
    recentData.sourceKey = "fdfdf"
    recentData.sourceEnabled = true
    recentData.sourceUnlocked = false
    recentData.type?.typeOfNews = "fdfdfd"

    try! realm.write({ () -> Void in
        realm.add(recentData)

    })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize your property first with a related object, before you can write values on it. I'd recommend to that in a separate variable like shown below, so you can avoid writing on an optional value (`recentData.type?.typeOfNews = …`):

```
let type = SourceType()
type.typeOfNews = "fdfdfd"
recentData.type = type
```

You can query for the object like that:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let objects = realm.objects(SourceRecentData).filter("type.id = 1")
```

PS: I'd recommend to name your classes beginning with an uppercase letter as this is a general best-practice in the Swift programming community and make it easier to differentiate between classes and variables. I applied that in the following example code to make it easier to read, because SO's syntax highlighting relies on that convention as well.

Comment: Why not `filter("type.id = 1")`?

Comment: That should work as well. I edited to post, because my previous predicate used mistakenly a wrong placeholder. Thanks @MJQZ1347.

Answer (score 1):

Won't `recentData.type?.typeOfNews = "fdfdfd"` be a non operation? It will be a None "value" by default.

You need to create an instance of `sourceType`, set the property, and then assign that to `recentData.type`.